# Issue getting crypto (from PyCrypto) installed to an updated version

Tags: python

Im using the crypto package, and theres a particular feature that I want to use - 
`from Crypto import Random`

However, my version of crypto is too low.  Random is only available in crypto  version 2.1, and running this command prints out that my version is too low -

```
print(Crypto.__version__)
2.0.1
```

Im trying to update crypto, but running a `pip install --upgrade crypto` returns that everything is up to date -

```
Requirement already up-to-date: crypto in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: Naked in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages (from crypto)
Requirement already up-to-date: shellescape in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages (from crypto)
Requirement already up-to-date: requests in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages (from Naked->crypto)
Requirement already up-to-date: pyyaml in /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages (from Naked->crypto)
```

How can I get this crypto version updated to 2.1?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be installing [`pycrypto` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto), not `crypto`:

```
pip install --upgrade pycrypto
```

---

As a side note, I'm not sure about your use cases, but we've switched from `pycrypto` to a more actively developed and modern crypto-package called [`cryptography`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cryptography) - works for us perfectly.

Comment: Ill check it out.  Thanks for the help! I'll accept the answer when the 9 minutes is up.